# Angular Font Awesome in google.maps.InfoWindow

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-fontawesome

Display Font Awesome 5 icon in Google Maps Info Window (API)

FA5 works as expected in my Angular application when used in the html templates. But when using the `google.maps.InfoWindow` we're outside Angular, and I'm not able to use e.g

`<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'location-arrow']"></fa-icon>`
in the content html string.

We also want everything to be packaged before runtime, so no runtime calls for js or css for FA.

The Google Maps info window has a button like this:

```
drawInfoWindow() {
    this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:
        "<div class='info-window'>"+
        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-vn btn-md btn-default'><div class='fas-wrapper'><fa-icon [icon]=\"['fas', 'location-arrow']\"></fa-icon></div> Navigate</button>"+
        "</div>"
    });
}
```

I also added `"./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",` to angular.json in case it could be of any use.

Before upgrading to FA5, I used `<i class='fas fa-location-arrow'></i>`, 
which worked well, but then I also used the kit.fontawesome.com/*** in my index.html.

I take it that I have to manually render the icon in my map-component.ts file, and pass it in to my `drawInfoWindow` function? But I'm at a loss as to where to start. Any suggetions?

Cheers!

Comment: 1. Yes, you will need to render SVG manually for this use case. You can use `icon` function from `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` package to convert icon name into the rendered SVG (check this [comment](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/72#issuecomment-466410777) and let me know if you need further help). 2. As for the automatic CSS insertion, I would recommend to use styles from `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` as they are used by the fa-icon component (see [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/48#issuecomment-432543956)).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!
I had a look at your comment and the links there, but I'm a bit too new to Angular.
As I need this in a Google Maps Info Window, I can't use a reference to the HTML template file. Wrapping the content of my `drawInfoWindow` function in `<ng-container #refForCalling>` doesn't work either, as it is outside Angular.

Do you know of an example of rendering the icon without using a html template #ref for displaying it?

Of course it does work to write the whole svg string in the info window `content` output, but I'd rather not do that :)

Comment: I'm not a big expert in Google Maps API, but from your example it looks like it wants you to pass the content as a string with HTML. `icon` function is the most clean way to acquire the icon markup. I don't really see how Angular needs to be used or can help in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much!
All I had to do was

```import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faLocationArrow } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';```

and then use `icon(faLocationArrow).html` in my info window content.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing

```
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faLocationArrow } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

I could use the icon function in my info window content html:
`icon(faLocationArrow).html`

Thank you to Yaroslav Admin!